# Toast in Firemonkey with onClick & additional TLabel/TText?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, toast

[image]

I'm using the opensource fmx.toast.pas - it's a TComponent.
FMXComponents: Firemonkey Opensource Components Set

Does anyone have a link to a free/opensource Toast that can do similar as to what Whatsapp Toast does?  - can click on Text such as 'open' to perform an action, or [x] to close it - text can be different colour (which means must be able to support 2 text)?

I searched a fair bit but can't find something that can do the above.

If no ready ones, can give some pointers on how to start to modify this component? especially how to add OnClick events and TLabel/TText to it?

Comment: try a look at https://github.com/yangyxd/FMXUI they have the dialog control that you could use for this purpose, also their toast control is delphi control so you can add things to it as you like.

Comment: also out of curiosity can you share the link to the opensource controls you are using

Comment: You can call your own popup/toast form directly in your required form. Design the form with your needs. Send your parameters to constructor and bind them to local variables for your form.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout https://github.com/zhaoyipeng/FMXComponents